# Javascript using local variable for function property string

Tags: javascript

Can't use variable to set date dynamically in my events? Using my "curr_date" variable below, I want to use this to pass to the events property of the function, such as the string literal is passed but it is not working.

```
var curr_date = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;

$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
    time: yyyy+'-'+mm,
    events: {
      "2016-12-03": {"number": 1},
      curr_date : {}}
  });
});
```

I know there might be already similar questions to this, however, I do not know the exact wording of what I am trying to accomplish thus my posting.

Comment: Please define "_not working_".

Comment: use `[curr_date]: {}`

Comment: @Thomas bro thank you, I am pretty new to js,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var curr_date = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var events = {
        time: yyyy+'-'+mm,
        events: {
          "2016-12-03": {"number": 1}
        }
      }
      events.events[curr_date] = {};
      $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar(events);
    });
```